# procedure execute 'ret' but not execute it

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I write the GreatCommonDivisor and use have declare ret down the `repeat....until`, but find it still go into the `repeat ..... until` and cause division by zero error.

I think that `ret` pop the address that the caller's next line, but why it jump into the `repeat...until`?

```
ps:eax is dividend and ebx is divisor.
```

Thx in advance.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data

.code
main PROC
mov eax, 75
mov ebx, 18
call gcd
main ENDP


gcd PROC 

or eax,eax;set SF
.IF Sign?
    Neg eax
.Else 
.EndIf

or ebx,ebx;set SF
.IF Sign?
    Neg ebx
.Else 
.EndIf

.Repeat 
mov edx, 0
div ebx

mov eax, ebx
mov ebx, edx    
.Until ebx <= 0

call WriteInt
ret
gcd ENDP

END main
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you made `main` a `PROC`. There's also a possibility that, due to how you've ordered your code, it will proceed with executing `gcd` again after reaching the end of `main` (I don't have MASM handy on this machine to verify this).

I'd structure the program like this:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
.code

gcd PROC 
; gcd implementation omitted for brevity..
ret
gcd ENDP

main:
mov eax, 75
mov ebx, 18
call gcd

END main
```

Comment: It work fine when I change it but why the order will have such different sequence?

Comment: Your `main` doesn't end with an `ExitProcess` call or a `ret`, so it will just keep executing whatever comes after it (which was `gcd` in the original version). To be entirely correct you should really use `invoke ExitProcess,0` to exit back to Windows.